# Inserting an element in a list while keeping the order

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ordered list `a=[1.1, 2., 4.5]`. I want to create a new list `b` consisting in the previous list with an element `l=3.1` inserted in such a way that `b` is still ordered.

I would do it using `numpy` in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
b=a[:np.searchsorted(a, l)]+[l]+a[np.searchsorted(a, l):]
```

are there more synthetic ways, for example with some specific `numpy` function ?

Comment: Depending what your overall goal is, you may get away with a heap (`heapq`). It doesn't keep your list sorted, but it does guarantee that you can pull the minimum value from it efficiently. This can be more efficient in total than to keep your list sorted after each insertion.

Comment: Numpy insert probably better once you've converted to an array (which searchsorted does implicitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can use [`bisect.insort_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

```
from bisect import insort_left
a=[1.1, 2., 4.5]
insort_left(a, 3.1)
```